# Calling a Weather API in React/.NET - how to set the value of a form to the city in the API call

Tags: .net, reactjs, api

I'm creating a React / .NET application that makes an API call to the OpenWeather API. It works fine when I hard code in the location of the city. However, I wanted the user to be able to input their current city into a form, press submit, and have the weather details updated. Here is my current code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { temp: "", summary: "", city: "", location: "London" };
  }

  getData() {
    fetch("api/weather/city/" + encodeURIComponent(this.state.location))
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data =>
        this.setState({
          temp: data.temp,
          summary: data.summary,
          city: data.city
        })
      );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <center>
          <h1>Weather</h1>
          <p>Please enter your city:</p>
          <form onSubmit={() => this.getData()}>
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Type city here..."
              value={this.state.location}
              onChange={e => this.setState({ location: e.target.value })}
            />
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          </form>
          <h4>City</h4>
          <p>{this.state.city}</p>
          <h4>Temperature</h4>
          <p> {this.state.temp}</p>
          <h4>Description</h4>
          <p> {this.state.summary}</p>
        </center>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Whenever I type in a city and press submit, no API data is displayed. However, I have tested the API call and this works correctly. Is anyone able to help advise how I can get the user's input to update the `this.state.location` and display the weather for that city?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Why are you using encodeURIComponent?
Simply use the this.state.location.
Since the openweather api is as follows,
api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London.
Names will be sufficent

Comment: The code as it is _should_ work. Do you see any errors in console?

Comment: Try passing the selected input value to getdata function from jsx itself or try Comoponentonupdate function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if your api is giving right result, the page would refresh due to native browser submit functionality.

You should avoid default refresh on submit by using `event.preventDefault`

```
<form onSubmit={(e) => this.getData(e)}>

getData(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
```

Let me know if any other error occurs.

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: Hi, @juemura7  your mapping also needed to be corrected as I mentioned on my answer (if the api is openweathermap.org )

Comment: Hi @SuleymanSah - thanks so much, it actually works though as I have called the API in my backend code and the call in the front end is calling my C# method

Answer (score 0):

You seem to map wrong values from api result.

temp must be taken from: data.main.temp

summary must be taken from: data.weather[0].description

Also as suggested in the comments, encodeURIComponent  looks unnecessary.

Your getData function must be like this.
I added    e.preventDefault();  and corrected the mappings.

```
  getData = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
     fetch("api/weather/city/" + encodeURIComponent(this.state.location))
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data =>
        {
         this.setState({
          temp: data.main.temp,
          summary: data.weather[0].description,
          city: data.name
        })
        }
      ).catch(err => console.log("err:", err));
  }
```

And formSubmit line can changed to:

```
 <form onSubmit={this.getData}>
```